Breakpoints in VS Code not working when C++ built with Bazel and launched with GDB
Using Windows, I'm in a simple repository in my Documents folder, where I build a c++ file which I want to debug.
I tried multiple outputs of bazel (see the commented out program attributes), but all except the one commented in, do launch, but don't stop at all - neither on entry, nor on breakpoints. The on commented in does stop on entry, but returns a weird filepath. It's not in my documents folder, but on the Desktop, despite the Desktop being empty. Also the path is duplicated:
C:\Users\peter\Desktop\simple_project\C\Users\peter\Desktop\simple_project\main.cc
This seems like to me, that GDB has the wrong path in the debug symbols compiled in.
Do you think this might be the issue, and if so, how can I specify that the correct symbols should be compiled into?
This is my launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Bazel Debug",
      "preLaunchTask": "Bazel build (debug)",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bazel-${workspaceFolderBasename}/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      // "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bazel-out/x64_windows-dbg/bin/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      //"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bazel-bin/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "targetArchitecture": "x64",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-${workspaceFolderBasename}": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

According tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Bazel build (debug)",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bazel build --compiler=C:\\ProgramData\\cygwin64\\bin\\g++.exe --strip=never -c dbg //...",
      "group": "build"
    }
  ]
}


yor program should point to executables in dbg folders inside bazel-out.
So something like below should work:-
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bazel-out/k8-dbg/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe".
